# SQL Server 2012 SP1 transaction log getting full?

Tags: sql-server

One of my DBs is having a problem with the transaction log filling up. It's set to full recovery and is regularly being backup via maintenance plan. I have a full DB backup every weekend then daily differential backups during the weekday along with the transaction log backup every hour. I checked log truncation status and the current status is LOG_BACKUP. I can clear it out doing a on-demand backup but why isn't it being cleared out with the maintenance plan?

What am I missing?

Comment: Katherine has some good points. I'd suggest checking your autogrowth settings on the log file, also. If the log cant grow when it gets full, you could run into a nasty issue where the logfile runs out of space and then sql will throw a 9002 error. I'd also recommend reducing your transaction log backups to a :30 frequency. Any new software or anything that is causing the log file to take up more space in that hour timespan?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer - to clarify my flag -- Kris, sorry it's a canned comment from the review queue.  For me I saw it as a rehash of Katherine's answer followed by a question which might have been better suited as +1 her answer and then commenting on hers and the OP.

Comment: Not a problem.  Thanks for relocating this to comments, I see what you are saying.

Comment: And it was MarkHenderson that relocated it...just to clarify.  So ultimately if I was being boneheaded, the mods would've told me so. :)

Answer (score 4):

You might need to back up your transaction logs more frequently than hourly if your database has a lot of transactions.  Every 15 minutes isn't uncommon.  I'd suggest editing the maintenance job to run log backups more frequently.

Also, does the .ldf have enough disk space?  If the physical file is prevented from growing, it'll run out of space even with truncation.

Comment: The first time it happened I increased the size of the log as a band-aid to keep the app running and there is plenty of actual disk space left. I'll try 15 minutes and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

A few things impact whether or not SQL Server's transaction log will show as "full" or need to grow:

- Long running transactions
- Frequency of log backups when in full or bulk logged recovery model
- The number and size of Virtual Log Files (vlfs) in the transaction log

Jes Schultz Borland has a free video where she describes how this all works in much greater detail, it sounds like it'd help you out: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/09/how-sql-server-works-log-file-video/

When it's important to avoid data loss, running log backups every *one* minute isn't unusual. It's all about how much data it's OK to lose in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. Happens if you are never making a backup. Similar to the tank in your car getting empty if you never bother to do your job and fill it up.

Transaction logs should get deleted after a full or incremental backup - if you do not make backups then put the database model to Simple.

If you regularly do full backups then obviously someone did not know how to make them and forgot to put the deletion of the transaction log into the sequence. The maintenance plan has a setting for that.

THAT SAID: if you run something like replication that may block the log if you fall behind.

Comment: "Transaction logs should get deleted after a full or incremental backup" --Absolutely not.  I retain 2 weeks worth.  What happens if your his most recent full backup isn't valid or gets corrupted. What about if a differential gets borked?  If that's the case, then log backups are the only way the OP can restore.  You should not just 'delete log backups that were made before your full/diff backups'.

Comment: "If you regularly do full backups then obviously someone did not know how to make them and forgot to put the deletion of the transaction log into the sequence" --Absolutely not, again.  When log backups are taken, the log file is TRUNCATED and any completed/committed transactions are flushed to disk.  The portions of the log file (stored in VLFs) that were flushed are then marked for reuse and can be written to again.  This is done every single time the log is backed up.  Hourly, in this case.